# The error occurs when using Android Compose LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid within a scrollable layout

Tags: android, scroll, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I want to enable scrolling for the entire MyScreen, but when I add verticalScroll to the Column, an error occurs.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        repeat(30) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .background(if (it % 2 == 0) Color.DarkGray else Color.Gray)
            )
        }
        LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
            columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
        ) {
            repeat(30) {
                item() {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(50.dp)
                            .background(Color.DarkGray)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to integrate the LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid component into MyScreen and enable the entire screen to be scrollable. What is the recommended approach to achieve this?